# Search with dynamic results

Tags: search, craft3

A couple questions...

1) How do these dynamic searches work? A excellent example is found at [McMaster Carr website](https://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-socket-head-screws/=1bxdrjl)

2) Is there any search plugin like that for Craft? I did not see any.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a "search" plugin for that. Craft has a brilliant Query Builder so it can be done really easily. Furthermore there is the `Element Api` which provides a JSON endpoint.

I suggest you to read the docs about [Searching in Craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/searching) and about [Queries in Templates](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/templating/querying-elements/index.md).

If you wan't to search for entries containing these words, a specific `length` and a `threadSize` you could do

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.threadSize('and, >0, <80).length('and, >10, <100).search({
    query: 'socket head screws',
    subLeft: true,
    subRight: true                
}).limit(10).all() %}
    <article>
        <h1><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h1>
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">Continue reading</a>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

That's basically it.

For advanced searches I would recommend to create a custom plugin. It's totally easy to search things in Craft so the need of a "default" plugins is not really high and it's faster to create a custom plugin than to find one that fits all your specific needs.